# what is the most efficient way to sum over all observations in previous years

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, plyr

I have a similar data set to the following

For each unique year, I would like to sum over all treaties each unique id in the data set has. What is the best approach for such a problem? My dataset is much larger than the example here. I have heard that `for loops` are inefficient to do this.

```
id <- rep(1:3, 4)
year <- (c(c(rep(1990, 3)), c(rep(1991, 3)), c(rep(1992, 3)), c(rep(1993, 3))) )
treaty <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 )
data <- cbind(id, year, treaty)
```

What I have tried is something like this, but I haven't managed that it works. Could I also do this with the `plyr` or `dplyr` package?

```
for (i in unique(data$year)){
for (j in unique(data$year)){
  prior_temp <- sum(dat$treaty[which(dat$id==j & yearunique[1:i])])
 }
   dat$prior <- prior_temp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *prior* you mean the current and prior years for that `id` then:

```
transform(data, prior = ave(treaty, id, FUN = cumsum))
```

or if you really mean prior years for that `id` then:

```
transform(data, prior = ave(treaty, id, FUN = cumsum) - treaty)
```

With dplyr it would be this or replace `cumsum(treaty)` with `cumsum(treaty) - treaty` if you really mean prior.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(prior = cumsum(treaty)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Wow! That's great. Yes really mean prior `years` for that `id`. Thank you so much!